Movie about a carpenter pretending to be a priest
I saw this movie a long time ago and I want to know its name. The movie is in English and is set in the 90's or 00's. 
It's about a carpenter working in a church. He's in the confessional box and a girl shows up. She thinks he is the priest so she confesses to him that she is feeling the desire to have sex with other men, possibly because she's about to get married. He looks for her (he wants to get laid with her) and somehow they become friends but they start to fall in love. 
At the end, he officiates the marriage between the girl and her fiancé , but then, the family discovers he's a fake priest and have to do another wedding, of course, without inviting him. He's desperate because he really loves her. The father of the bride (or someone else?) tells him about the new place and he crashes the wedding. There, he confesses her love and meanwhile she's thinking about his words, she lets her ring fall and it's like a signal or something like this because she runs away with him.
I also remember that the sister's carpenter is a motorcyclist and in the end she flirts with the groom (who was already dumped).

This is the romantic comedy My First Wedding from 2006. 

A young lady (Rachael Leigh Cook) about to get married realizes that she has a problem: she fantasizes about every man she sees. She goes to confess at church but unknowingly confesses to a young man (Kenny Doughty) who is not a priest [but rather a carpenter repairing the confessional]. He agrees to help her, but falls in love with her along the way. Unfortunately she still thinks he is a priest.

Here's the trailer, where you can see some of the scenes you mentioned:




seems like, according to imdb, the argentinean verison is higher rated than the original movie!
